# Can Two Load balancers have same ssl endpoint and certificate

Tags: deployment, load-balancing, high-availability, cloudhub

One of my application is running behind a Load balancer on a server in `east region`. I have created a replica of the same application and deployed it on a server in `west` region

My question is, that can I achieve High availability using two load balancers?
Something Like

1. Application running in EAST region behind load balancer LB-1 (Primary)
2. If we shut down the above, then Application running in WEST region should become active which is running behind LB-2.

My thoughts:

1. Replication Of Code on deployment: Write Jenkins script which will trigger a deploy command to deploy APP TO `west` REGION, whenever a deployment is done on `east` region.
2. CHecking the health of primary Server/application: Write cron, which will check if the server on `east` region is down
3. If it is down, then
   a. Using Load Balancer `PATCH` API, remove the mapping of load balancer in `EAST` region.
   b. Using Load Balancer `PATCH` API, update the mapping of load balancer in `WEST` region [To match with the previous east region mappings]

Are these feasible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that each Dedicated Load Balancer has a unique DNS host name in CloudHub. And the certificate subject's common name attribute must match the host name to avoid SSL/TLS validation errors in the clients.

If you are intending to failover transparently for the clients, meaning that the next requests go through LB-2, then you should have a [DNS CNAME record](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/lb-architecture#renaming-external-mule-application-urls-through-a-dedicated-load-balancer) that matches LB-1 and you need to point to LB-2. If you don't have a DNS CNAME record to point to the other dedicated load balancer, then you need to change the clients URL to point to LB-2, and need to be sure that the certificate has a [Subject Alternative Name](https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/what-is-ssl-san/) with LB-2 host name, so it is valid for both.